# Unable to rollback java appengine transaction at email validation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rollback

I keep getting prompted for the email and password for the account. I am using the same exact credentials to get into the dashboard. Has anyone seen this?

I also do not know the folder it is referencing is located.

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Rolling back the update.
Dec 10, 2014 8:06:49 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/rollback?
app_id=rostr361&version=1&
401 Unauthorized
Must authenticate first.
This is try #0
Email: something@gmail.com
Password for something@gmail.com: 
Email: something@gmail.com
Password for something@gmail.com: 
Email: something@gmail.com
Password for something@gmail.com: 
Unable to rollback app: Email "something@gmail.com" and password do not match.
Please see the logs 
[/var/folders/v7/07l6w61s2ydb1b0h4twtn3xr0000gn/T/appcfg3718602673335362067.log] for further 
information.
```

Comment: Same problem here. I also keep getting prompted for the email and password. And am entering the same credentials as in my email login. But still it doesn't work. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did sorry. You have to use terminal. Let me find the link.

Comment: try this:

appcfg.sh [options] rollback --oauth2 <war-location>

Sorry I took so long

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Programatic How you resolved issue? I dont understand command you have given

Comment: @Programmer I had to `cd` to the <war-location>, then `<path-to-appcfg>/appcfg.cmd --oath2 rollback .`.

Answer (score 0):

```
./appcfg.sh --oauth2 rollback <app location>
```

Example app location: ***/home/Project2/Server/src/main/webapp/***

It will give a link.

Click on the link and select the appropriate email account. It will give something like this. **4/yYS7HljpeI8_SZvwRwQFFV8zxLMyLEFp4hxQbjqtXlY**

Enter that code in terminal.

Then you are done